# Android emulator browser can't access to localhost subdomains set on hosts file

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, hosts

In my current Android Emulator with API 26 I'm trying to access with it's browser to a localhost subdomain set in the android emulator hosts file with no success.

I successfully managed to root my emulator and modify it's `/etc/hosts` file (pushing a local file and with [busybox](https://busybox.net/) mini **vi** implementation). Some of the successful tests that I made in the browser and with the `ping` command from `adb shell` are as follows (where 192.168.0.10 is my current assigned host ip):

```
192.168.0.10   source
192.168.0.10   source.api
192.168.0.10   source.api.local
10.0.2.2       source
10.0.2.2       source.api
10.0.2.2       source.api.local
```

but with localhosts subdomains mappings I can only ping the domain from `adb shell` with success. The browser displays an `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error in the next host mappings:

```
10.0.2.2       something.localhost
10.0.2.2       something.something.localhost
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

**EDIT:**

The current problem only happens in my macOS 10.14, I couldn't reproduce the problem in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the [Multicast DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local#mDNS_implementations) (mDNS) implementation of macOS, when using the top-level domain `.local`

> Bonjour... "will automatically resolve the private IP addresses of link-local Macintosh computers running MacOS and mobile devices running iOS if .local is appended to their hostnames."

[RFC 6762 Appendix G](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6762#appendix-G) recomends the following private namespaces instead of .local|.localhost to avoid conflicts.

- .intranet.
- .internal.
- .private.
- .corp.
- .home.
- .lan.